# firefox high memory (RAM) usage, how to free with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory, ram

I notice that after using firefox for a couple of hours it gets more that 2gb of ram memory. It happens expecially when I upload big files (100mb-400mb) with ajax uploader, and also happens when I open to many images (for example 16mb of total images on a web page).

The problem is that even after upload finish or after closing the images pages the memory is not getting free, firefox still have 2gb of ram memory.
Is there a way from javascript to make firefox free the memory, for example when upload finish or after images are loaded or closed?

**EDIT**
From `about:memory` :
1,172.03 MB (100.0%) -- explicit

├──1,000.00 MB (85.32%) -- js

│  ├────863.97 MB (73.72%) -- compartment([System Principal], 0x5083000)

│  │    ├──819.31 MB (69.91%) ── string-chars

How can I empty **string-chars** that I am pretty sure this comes when the files are readed into memory and then uploaded with ajax?

**EDIT 2**

Here is the recrusive function causing this memory usage:

```
function uploadAjax(file, startByte, index)
{
    if(startByte==0)
    {
        $('#progress'+index).html(' ').progressbar( "destroy" ).progressbar();
        $('#asyncuploadsingle'+index).attr('disabled', true);
    }

    var size        = file.size;
    var chunkSize   = 2097152;//2 megabyte
    var endByte     = chunkSize + startByte;
    var isLast      = (size - endByte <= 0);
    var chunk       = file;
    var xhr         = new XMLHttpRequest();//prepare xhr for upload
    var chunkNum    = endByte / chunkSize;

    if(chunkSize == 0)//no divide
    {
        chunk   = file;
        isLast  = true;
    }
    else if(file.mozSlice) // moz slice
    {
        chunk   = file.mozSlice(startByte, endByte);
    }
    else if(file.webkitSlice) //webkit slice
    {
        chunk   = file.webkitSlice(startByte, endByte);
    }
    else if(file.slice) // w3c slice
    {
        chunk   = file.slice(startByte, chunkSize);
    }
    else
    {
        chunk   = file;
        isLast  = true;
    }

    //progress function, with ajax upload progress can be monitored
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e)
    {
        if (e.lengthComputable) 
        {
            var perc = Math.round((e.loaded + chunkNum * chunkSize - chunkSize) * 100 / size);
            //console.log(perc+':'+index);
            $('#progress'+index).progressbar("option", "value", perc);
        }  
    }, false); 

    xhr.upload.onabort=function(e)  {   
        finishUp(index,'Aborted');
    };  

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('error', function(e){
        finishUp(index, this.responseText+'--->'+name);
    }, false);  

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            try
            {
                var ret = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                if(isLast)
                {
                    finishUp(index,'');
                }
                else if(ret.status == 'error')
                {
                    throw ret.info;
                }
                else
                {
                    uploadAjax(file, endByte, index);
                }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                finishUp(index, err);
            }

            delete chunk;
        }
    };

    var path    = get_final_path();
    var url     = "filetransfer/uploadfiles.php?ax-file-name="+encodeURIComponent(file.name)+"&ax-file-path="+encodeURIComponent(path)+'&ax-start-byte='+startByte;

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');//header
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');//generic stream header

    /*var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {  
        xhr.sendAsBinary(evt.target.result);  
    };  
    reader.readAsBinaryString(chunk);
    */  
    xhr.send(chunk);

    return xhr;
}
```

Any point where to optimize it or where to free objects?

Comment: Have you tried closing the tab? What's the version?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can visit `about:memory`, but that's it.

Comment: Ajax file uploader? Now that sounds **very** interesting (sarcasm here). As for your question: impossible.

Comment: the versions of firefox are from 5-13

Comment: @albanx You have to clear all references to this data. If you have a lot of scoping, then this might not be an easy task (in some cases impossible). Only then the browser will free the memory (at some point at least). By the way: quite interesting library you have there. I'll look at it later. Remember that it is impossible to upload files via AJAX (unless browser supports HTML5). So how do they do that so it works with older browsers? Mostly some tricks with iframes. This might be related to your problem.

Comment: I am trying do to this just right now with `delete object`

Answer (score 2):

I use Memoryfox addon to keep firefox's memory to a minimum. Though I use it only for the browser (don't enable 'All Processes' option) since I run Photoshop/Lightroom a lot and it tends to interfere with them in All Processes mode (it's quite aggressive).

[Memory Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-fox/)

Though even with that firefox will still inflate. The best approach is to remove any addons you don't use and disable those you don't use often. If you have a lot of plugins there are some which cause major memory issues with firefox and some of those are highlighted under the [MemShrink project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance/MemShrink).

With reference specifically to the code supplied in your edits, there are a couple of reasons why you may be seeing additional memory usage:

1) The use of anonymous functions means a new function is created in-memory for each and every one each time uploadAjax is run. Define your functions outside uploadAjax then reference them to avoid duplicates in-memory.

2) `delete xhr;` when you're done with it. It's not usually required but if you're performing lots of uploads, it may be leaving some stuff behind.

3) You're essentially calling `uploadAjax(file, endByte, index);` both recursively and inside an anonymous function, which means everything you create in the higher-level calls may still exist whilst the lower level calls execute. This will lead to multiple in-memory `xhr` and `chunk`. Consider calling `uploadAjax` in a different way (such as by triggering an event then accessing the same file and xhr from a global, or on a short timer so as to introduce an execution disconnect. I'd probably favour the former though hard to say for sure without testing it myself).

Comment: the problem is that I am developening this uploaders and I do not want this to happen in the client browser, not in mine.

Comment: Oh, this is nice. Looks like it even integrates those functions from `about:memory` I brought up in my answer.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about memory usage in the client's browser, it's up to them to manage their memory. The resticted scope of running in a browser means you have to live with whatever their browser does. You can however take various steps in your uploader script to clean up after itself. Ensure you explicitly `delete` anything you no-longer need so you're not leave garbage behind for the GC to miss.

Comment: added details pertaining specifically to the code in the question authors edits

Answer (score 1):

It's not what you want, but it sounds like this is what you need:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-restart/

You can set threshold values for alerts, and even have it auto-restart.

(Though, as I just discovered courtesy of Rob W, `about:memory` allows you to garbage collect and do other memory cleanups (in Firefox 13, at least; haven't checked how far back it goes as I don't have previous versions of Firefox on this machine and I don't really have the time to download and install previous versions to test). Pretty neat. You might want to try using that first even if it isn't automatic if auto-restarts of Firefox aren't to your liking.)

Comment: the problem is that I am developening this uploaders and some web application and I do not want this problem to happen in the client browser, not in mine.

Answer (score 0):

That's the worst thing happening behind firefox... I used to have this problem as well. The thing is that you have to restart your browser, so some memory will be free, but not all. That the main problem for One Page Application which is mainly use dom replacement without refreshing page.

Comment: that exctely the problem I have, so I am worried about users that uses my web app

Comment: That's the main problem for One Page Application, and it's very difficult to solve this problem. You must clear all dom that you stop using, not just hide, and show.

Answer (score 0):

There is no javascript API within firefox to help resolve your issue.  Memory usage in Firefox has been one of the longest-standing complaints, despite much work to improve the footprint.  Your options are mostly limited to:

(a) restarting firefox in order to kill the process and free it's allocated memory

(b) using 3rd party utilities or plugins for either Firefox or Windows to help free some of its memory

(c) using a different browser, such as Chrome, which uses a process-per-tab model which helps mitigate memory usage concerns

FYI - [here's some more info from a Mozilla knowledgebase](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Memory_Leak)